# Array of Code from a database generated in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have inherited this lovely code and I have found the following in the database. Can someone tell me what kind of array this is so that I can pull out the information? I am using Codeigniter PHP Framework: -

```
a:70:{i:0;s:19:"Antigua and Barbuda";i:1;s:9:"Australia";i:2;s:7:"Austria";i:3;s:7:"Bahamas";i:4;s:7:"Bahrain";i:5;s:8:"Barbados";i:6;s:7:"Belgium";i:7;s:6:"Brunei";i:8;s:6:"Canada";i:9;s:4:"Cuba";i:10;s:6:"Cyprus";i:11;s:14:"Czech Republic";i:12;s:7:"Denmark";i:13;s:18:"Dominican Republic";i:14;s:5:"Egypt";i:15;s:7:"Estonia";i:16;s:4:"Fiji";i:17;s:7:"Finland";i:18;s:6:"France";i:19;s:7:"Germany";i:20;s:7:"Grenada";i:21;s:7:"Iceland";i:22;s:7:"Ireland";i:23;s:6:"Israel";i:24;s:5:"Italy";i:25;s:7:"Jamaica";i:26;s:5:"Japan";i:27;s:6:"Jordan";i:28;s:8:"Kiribati";i:29;s:12:"Korea, South";i:30;s:6:"Kuwait";i:31;s:13:"Liechtenstein";i:32;s:10:"Luxembourg";i:33;s:8:"Malaysia";i:34;s:8:"Maldives";i:35;s:5:"Malta";i:36;s:16:"Marshall Islands";i:37;s:10:"Micronesia";i:38;s:6:"Monaco";i:39;s:7:"Morocco";i:40;s:5:"Nauru";i:41;s:11:"Netherlands";i:42;s:11:"New Zealand";i:43;s:6:"Norway";i:44;s:4:"Oman";i:45;s:5:"Palau";i:46;s:16:"Papua New Guinea";i:47;s:8:"Portugal";i:48;s:5:"Qatar";i:49;s:18:"Russian Federation";i:50;s:21:"Saint Kitts and Nevis";i:51;s:11:"Saint Lucia";i:52;s:32:"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines";i:53;s:5:"Samoa";i:54;s:10:"San Marino";i:55;s:12:"Saudi Arabia";i:56;s:9:"Singapore";i:57;s:15:"Solomon Islands";i:58;s:5:"Spain";i:59;s:6:"Sweden";i:60;s:11:"Switzerland";i:61;s:8:"Thailand";i:62;s:5:"Tonga";i:63;s:19:"Trinidad and Tobago";i:64;s:6:"Turkey";i:65;s:6:"Tuvalu";i:66;s:20:"United Arab Emirates";i:67;s:13:"United States";i:68;s:7:"Vanuatu";i:69;s:5:"Yemen";}"
```

Comment: may be json encoded array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's returned when you use PHP's [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) function.

Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to turn that back into an array.

Comment: Perfect answer! I've been looking at it for so long I didn't even think of that. Thank you!